# Should we say "die ist sehr groß" or "sie ist sehr groß" when referring to a feminine object?

Tags: pronoun

I am new to German and I came across this sentence in a practice book. In reference to a couple's kitchen, a character says "die ist sehr groß". But from what I know, the sentence should have been "sie ist sehr groß" since "sie" is the personal pronoun for all nouns of feminine gender (and hence for (e)Küche).

Could someone please help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Parthu Shiva, I am pretty sure your question has already been answered here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23024/when-do-i-use-der-die-das-instead-of-er-sie-es - the chosen answer has an example with "Der" instead of "Er" -  "Die" and "Sie" for your kitchen work the same way here.

Comment: @subrunner, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. From what I have understood, "die" is sometimes used as a demonstrative pronoun and thus can be used interchangeably with "sie". Could you please confirm if my understanding is right or not?

Comment: @ParthuShiva: yes, that's right, you got it.

Comment: @HalvarF, Thanks a lot for the confirmation!